automate chatgpt prompts using Make (Integromat)
I have the following problem:
I have a view with a form that contains two inputs: one called employee and another called prompt.
The employee input is a dropdown select with the company's employees, and the prompt input allows a question, such as: How many hours did the employee work?
Then, this form is sent using JavaScript to a Make webhook (Make.com, formerly Integromat), which immediately responds with 200 Accepted.
In Make, a process starts that retrieves information about the user and then sends the query to OpenAI, returning a JSON response.
When the process in Make finishes, I need to display the text from that JSON in the container with id="Response" in my view.
The issue is that I don’t know when the Make process finishes because Make already responded with 200 Accepted.
I've read about a strategy called polling, where you periodically check if the response from ChatGPT is ready. However, I’m not sure if this is the best approach.
I’d like to know, conceptually, what you recommend. How can this be solved? Are there better alternatives to polling?
